# query to get all action during for each hour

Tags: c#, sql, linq

i want to run and print a query that shows the number of orders per each hour in a day(24).

should look like:
hour-1:00, number of orders-5
hour-2:00, number of orders-45
hour-3:00, number of orders-25
hour-4:00, number of orders-3
hour-5:00, number of orders-43
and so  on...

i try:

```
    public void ShowBestHours()
    {
        using (NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext())
        {
            var query =
                from z in db.Orders
                select new Stime
                {
                    HourTime = db.Orders.GroupBy(x => x.OrderDate.Value.Hour).Count(),

                };
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hour : {0},Order(s) Number : {1}", item.HourTime, item.Count);
            }
        }
    }
    public class Stime
    {
        public int HourTime { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: And what happens when you try?

Comment: Hour : 1,Order(s) Number : 0
Hour : 1,Order(s) Number : 0
Hour : 1,Order(s) Number : 0
and so on for many times...(i think the number of orders)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your query to

```
var query = 
    from z in db.Orders
    group z by z.OrderDate.Value.Hour into g
    select new Stime{ HourTime = g.Key, Count=g.Count () };
```

or alternatively

```
var query = db,Orders.GroupBy (o => o.OrderDate.Value.Hour).Select (
    g => new Stime{ HourTime=g.Key, Count=g.Count () });
```

In my copy of Northwind all of the OrderDate values are dates only so the result is just
HourTime = 0, Count = 830.

I'm assuming you're just experimenting with grouping. Try grouping by day of week like this

```
var query = db.Orders.GroupBy (o => o.OrderDate.Value.DayOfWeek).Select (
    g => new { DayOfWeek=g.Key, Count=g.Count () });
```

which gives a more useful result.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't setting `Stime.Count` anywhere in your query and you aren't grouping by hour correctly.  I haven't seen your exact setup of course, but I think the following should work for you.

```
var query =
    from z in db.Orders
    group z by z.OrderDate.Value.Hour into g
    select new Stime() { HourTime = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };

foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hour : {0},Order(s) Number : {1}", item.HourTime, item.Count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void ShowBestHours()
{
    using (NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext())
    {
        var query = db.Orders.GroupBy(x =>  x.OrderDate.Value.Hour).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).Select(x => new Stime { HourTime = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });   

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hour : {0},Order(s) Number : {1}", item.HourTime, item.Count);
        }
    }
}
```